# How can I prove that $S^n$ is a $n$-dim manifold?

Tags: general-topology

During proving another theorem, I need to prove that $S^n$ is an $n$-dim manifold that $S^n$ is a sphere  with unit diameter.how can I prove it?

any help would be great thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $U= S^n$ \ $(1,0,...,0)$, $V=S^n$ \ $(-1,0,...,0)$, with maps:

$\phi^{-1}: (x_0,...,x_n) \mapsto \frac{1}{1+x_0}(x_1,...,x_n)$ on $V$

$\psi^{-1}: (x_0,...,x_n) \mapsto \frac{1}{1-x_0}(x_1,...,x_n)$ on $U$

Prove these are homeomorphisms and you've got your theorem.